# Getting "Out of Stack space" error inconsistently

Tags: css, vba, excel, out-of-memory

On every page of my workbook, I have a status bar made of status boxes. There are three statuses -- "Tab Started", "Design Updated", and "Configurations Complete". Originally I had these boxes called out on every page (and using absolute references), but I recently tried to improve the efficiency and flexibility of the workbook by moving that code to a separate module and calling it on every workbook page near the top (+ setting variables using "Find" rather than absolute references).

However, while this works 90% of the time or more, occasionally I get an error message "Out of Stack Space". Reading on the MSDN, none of the examples that might trigger this error seem to apply to my code (e.g. the code doesn't call itself).

See below for code.

```
'This function is called by all workbook tabs and controls the status boxes

Sub StatusBars(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim TabStarted1 As Range
Set TabStarted1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:Z5").Find("Tab Started")
Dim TabStarted As Range
Set TabStarted = TabStarted1.Offset(0, 1) 

Dim Design1 As Range
Set Design1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A6:Z7").Find("Design Updated")
Dim Design As Range
Set Design = Design1.Offset(0, 1)

Dim Configurations1 As Range
Set Configurations1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A8:Z9").Find("Configurations Complete")
Dim Configurations As Range
Set Configurations = Configurations1.Offset(0, 1)

If Not Intersect(Target, TabStarted) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count = 2 Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target) = 0 Then 'If box is empty, then add an X, format it, change the box color and the tab color

            TabStarted.Value = "X"
            TabStarted.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            TabStarted.Font.Size = 25
            TabStarted.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            Design.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Design.Value = ""
            Configurations.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Configurations.Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

        Else 'if box is already checked clear, the X, the color, and the tab color
            TabStarted.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            TabStarted.Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
       End If
    End If

End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Design) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count = 2 Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target) = 0 Then
            Design.Value = "X"
            Design.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            Design.Font.Size = 25
            Design.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
            TabStarted.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            TabStarted.Value = ""
            Configurations.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Configurations.Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)

        Else
            Design.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Design.Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        End If
    End If

End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Configurations) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count = 2 Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target) = 0 Then
            Configurations.Value = "X"
            Configurations.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            Configurations.Font.Size = 25
            Configurations.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
            TabStarted.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            TabStarted.Value = ""
            Design.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Design.Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)

        Else
            Configurations.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Configurations.Value = ""
            ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        End If
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

EDIT:
An example of the code that calls this function:

```
'Remove Case Sensitivity
  Option Compare Text

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim var1 As Variant
Dim var2 As Variant
Dim var3 As Variant

Dim PlusTemplates As Range
Set PlusTemplates = Range("A14:Z15").Find("+")

Call StatusBars(Target)

[rest of the code]
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you also show the code, that calls the `Sub StatusBar`? I guess that you are entering a recursion without realizing it. E.g., you are calling from a `Worksheet_SelectChange` event, your code changes something, and you enter the event again and this is recursion.

Comment: And also the full error message?

Comment: @ahmet "Out of stack space" is the full error message. It's in the title *and* the body of the question.

Comment: Toggle `Application.EnableEvents` off at the start, and back on at the end of the procedure. Still out of stack space? If not, then your recursion is as @Vityata said: you're handling a worksheet event by calling this procedure, which modifies the worksheet, to which Excel responds by raising an event, which takes execution back to the worksheet event handler, only a few stack frames further down the call stack. Step through your code with the "call stack" debug toolwindow open, you'll see what's wrong and where.

Comment: @ahmet Because it's inconsistent, I can't reproduce with the rest of the error text. I've edited the post with an example of the code that calls it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I've updated to include EnableEvents, so we'll see if the error recurs. It's not something I can reproduce consistently. Because I'm using Excel for Mac 2016, I have no ability to enter the call stack debug tool window. My VBA editor is very bare bones.

Answer (score 0):

Activesheet is a global variable. When you set tabstarted1 etc. with Activesheet, because activesheet is on stack and did not disposed, your other variables like tabstarted1, design1 stays on stack memory. Try to get activesheet as parameter to your function.

Comment: What would that look like? If I call it via "Call StatusBars(Target, ActiveSheet), will I need to declare my Sub as: Sub StatusBars(ByVal Target As Range, ActiveSheet As Worksheet)? And what would that mean for the variables themselves -- would I still need to specify ActiveSheet.Range in my "Find"?

Comment: I dont know remember the syntax but it would propably be as you writtren in the comment. I am not sure, it fixs or not but as you try to refactor, you also should do that to encapsulate your variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because your code changes the sheet and thus a new event is called. To make sure that this is the case, do the following - insert a STOP on the event like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Stop

    Dim var1 As Variant
    'rest of your code.
End Sub
```

The first time you have a selection change you will stop on the stop. Then press <kbd>F5</kbd> and continue. If you stop again, then it is a recursion error.

The easiest way to fix it is with `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning of the event and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end of the code.

Comment: This seems to have helped with the stack space issue, but now if any other issue occurs, my Excel is essentially frozen because the EnableEvents hasn't been reenabled. Is there a downside to using .EnableEvents = True immediately after I call the StatusBars() function? I'm also still getting an occasional error (I believe it was the "With block variable not set" error) that highlights the "Set TabStarted = TabStarted1.Offset(0, 1)" line in the function.